# How to collect and work with the result in the manager process on Spring Batch remote chunking?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to configure a **Job** with a **remote chunking** **Step** using Spring Batch and Spring Batch Integration, and I am having some doubts.

I am using the `@EnableBatchIntegration` annotation, the `RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilderFactory` class to configure the **manager** and the `RemoteChunkingWorkerBuilder` class to configure the **worker**.

As far as I understood, I can do **write** on each **worker**, or I can get the results on the **manager** and **write** at the **manager step**. Is that correct? If yes, how can I do the **write** at the **manager step**?

It seems that the `ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter` in the manager is writing to my reply channel of my Middleware, which is a **RabbitMQ**, but I see the messages being consumed right after being delivered there.

I don't know where to go from here.

Does anyone can give me a help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `or I can get the results on the manager and write at the manager step. Is that correct?` How did you come to this conclusion? Can you please give a reference?

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine thanks for your response. To be honest, I don't remember where I read or watched something to understand this. Indeed, I already understood is not like this.

Comment: Indeed, I already understood is not like this. Maybe when I read the official documentation that says: "Taking things one step further, one can also externalize the chunk processing by using the ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter (provided by Spring Batch Integration), which sends items out and collects the result." https://docs-stage.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-chunking
I understood by "results" the result of a read and process inside a worker step.
I am sorry for the miss understanding.

Comment: Anyway, I have another question: Is it possible to scale out the managers?